# How to avoid ' sign when passing attribute JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Database text values will be displayed on HTML page and once the user clicks the paragraph `JQuery` an alert message will pop up with database values.

But the paragraph contains `"` and `'`. When passing `article-data` to `JQuery` it will pass text up to first `'` in the paragraph. How to solve this without doing any change in MySQL database?

```
<?php
    foreach ($data as $add) {
    echo "<div>";      
    echo "<p class='target' article-data='$add->p_content' >" . $add->p_id . $add->p_content . "</p>";
    echo "</div>"; 
}
?>

<script>
    //Display dialog box when mouse click 
    $( ".target" ).click(function() { 
       alert($(this).attr("article-data"));
    });       
</script>
```

Comment: What if you try php's `addslashes()` function around `$add->p_content` ?

Comment: `echo '<p class="target" article-data=""'.htmlspecialchars($add->p_content).'" >' . $add->p_id . $add->p_content . '</p>';`

Comment: @adam i don't want to remove it i want to get entire paragraph. But paragraph will end while find a ' of " sign

Comment: Here is a [phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/g2ai-gh09) showing how you can do this, just click "run" then click the text

Comment: it's work perfectly. can you please explain why `console.log` used?